How to delete old files and folders from azure app service manually?
I have my angular app deployed on Azure App Service, but when I deployed the new version of the application, the old files are not replaced by the new one and this causes 'Not Found error' for styles and fonts file in the deployed app, and I didn't got any particular instructions to do the same? so, how to remove the folders such as 'media', etc., from azure console.
I was trying to remove all the files from azure app service before redeploying the angular app to it.

Open the KUDU Console you can find the deployed files there.You can delete directly.

You can see your files in site/wwwroot directory.

URL for KUDU - YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net .Image

You can delete the deployed files directly from KUDU Console.
KUDU URL - https://AppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/
For Windows App Service:
KUDU =>Debug Console => CMD => C:\home\site\wwwroot>

You can directly remove the file/folder or run the command rmdir .

I have taken references from this MSDoc to remove its folder and sub files.


rmdir /S /Q SampleFolder


For Linux App Service:
URL - https://AppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui => File Manager => site/wwwroot


You can use the Azure App Service slots.
For example, if your app is running in production, deploy your updated app to a slot "myslotA" and then swap "myslotA" with production slot. Then you will have no unwanted files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest
